# How to do vaccuum sealed pack modeling in Blender?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

Does anyone How to model vacuum sealed packages like this? Can cloth simulation be used to model it?

[image: Vacuum Sealed Packs]

Answer (score 15):

<sup>(My other – previous – answer is from before Blender 2.82, when cloth pressure was introduced)</sup>

---

You can accurately simulate a vacuum sealed pack using cloth physics and negative pressure.

1. Enable *Physics > Collision* on your target objects
2. Model a mesh representing the "relaxed" bag around your objects; give it a good level of subdivision
   [image]
3. Select the vertices along the rim, and assign them to a vertex group with a weight of 0.6 - 0.7.
   [image]
   Another option is to only select one, or three, edges of the rim, to simulate different kinds of bags/vacuum apparatus.

   We use this to quickly create a "stiffer" rim. There are however better ways of doing this (like fine-tuning the structural springs parameters instead of the pin groups).
4. Enable *Physics > Cloth* on your bag.

   Parameters: I've mostly used the defaults, but

   - the *Quality Steps* must be higher, around 25
   - under *Shape > Pin group*, select the vertex group you created at step 3
   - under *Collision*, increase the *Quality* to around 8, and enable *Self collisions*
   - under *Field Weights*, remove (set as zero) the influence of *Gravity*
5. Lastly, **select a value around -100 for** ***Cloth > Pressure*** (in my example I've done it more gradually, going from 0 to -100 over 40 frames, but it turned out to be unnecessary)
6. Decrease the *Cache* length to around 40 frames, then *Bake*

   [image]
7. You can now go to the last frame and "*Apply*" the *Cloth Modifier* (if you want to get rid of the simulation)

   [image]

Comment: I wonder if Rich Colburn's [Modeling Cloth](https://github.com/the3dadvantage/Modeling-Cloth-2_8).. (whose code I've been learning a lot from) has played any part in this update. I would have reached for that, before.

Comment: I don't know :/ Here's the diff by Sebastian Parborg aka zeddb https://developer.blender.org/rBf6cefbef22c8

Comment: This looks much better than the earlier solutions!
Will try it soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

*Note: I've posted another answer after a new feature was added to Blender 2.82*

---

*Old answer:*

A cheap approach is using the **Shrinkwrap modifier**. It isn't properly a vacuum seal because the surface area of the sealant isn't preserved: a shrinkwrap effectively ...shrinks your mesh!

Use a highly subdivided mesh, put it all around your target, and use a Shrinkwrap modifier. Join all the objects to be wrapped into a single object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, and set this object as *Target* in the *Shrinkwrap* settings.

You can choose three different modes, *Nearest Vertex, Target Normal Project, Nearest Surface Point*: here's a demonstration (all use a slight offset and a smooth shader)

[image]

(see the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) for the explanations)

I wouldn't use *Project* for your purpose.